# Simulation with N trials in R

Tags: r, model, simulation

I am trying to create a simulation where a number 0:100 is chosen by a person, then a random number 0:100 is generated using `sample()`. The difference between their chosen number and the random number is calculated and stored. I would like to use a for loop to run this 10000 times and store the results in a vector so I can later plot the results. Can anyone point me to where I can read about this or see some examples? Below is what I have so far but I keep getting errors saying the lengths aren't the same multiple.

```
N = 10000
chosen.number = 0:100
generated.number = sample(0:100, N, replace = T)
differences = numeric(0)

for(i in 1:length(chosen.number)){
   differences = (generated.number - chosen.number)
}
```

Then I'll make a scatterplot of the vector `differences`.

Comment: Asking for recommendations is a good way to get your question closed down very quickly.  I'll just say that you're generating 10000 numbers, but choosing only 100.  And you can do this in R without using a loop.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example of how you could go about it (if I understand your questions correctly).

You can set how many loops you want using `Repeat`.

Since you want a different randomly generated number each time, you'll have to put `sample()` within your loop. I didn't know where your user-selected number would come from, but in this example, it gets randomly generated with the same set of criteria as the random selection.
Then differences are collected in `collect_differences` for you to use downstream.

```
Repeat = 10 # Number of times to repeat/loop

collect_differences <- NULL
for(i in 1:Repeat){
  randomly.generated.number = sample(0:100, size = 1, replace = T)
  selected.number = sample(0:100, size = 1, replace = T)
  differences = randomly.generated.number - selected.number

  collect_differences = c(collect_differences, differences)
}
collect_differences
```

As for resources, you can look up anything related to the fundamentals of [looping](https://ytakemon.github.io/2019-10-22-R-BCCRC/07-control-flow/). You could also look through [The Carpentries](https://carpentries.org/) lessons in R as they have some resources for this as well.

Comment: This did help, thanks! I wasn't using the c() function so my results were never properly stored

Comment: @Mercredi if this solved your issue, please accept it as the answer. That way other folks who stumble on this will know that it worked.